# REST Webservice with Weblogic12c + Jersey 1.18 + Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest, jersey, weblogic12c

I have been trying to build a basic RESTful webservice with Jersey 1.18 since yesterday but somehow couldn't deploy it in Weblogic when tried directly from eclipse. Later I just exported a war file from eclipse and deployed successfully with Weblogic Console. Is there anything else that I need to configure within eclipse in order to deploy a REST service (Jersey 1.18) directly from eclipse. Below are the sources and deployment descriptor :-

Resource Class :-

```
package com.ericsson.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Path("/TestResource")
public class TestResource {
    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public TestResource() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of TestResource
     * @return an instance of String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String resourceMethodGET() { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "<html>Hello Roy</html>";
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of TestResource
     * @content content representation for the resource
     * @return an HTTP response with content of the updated or created resource.
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes("text/html")
    public void resourceMethodPUT(String content) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

The application sub-class :-

```
package rest.application.config;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("test")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return getRestClasses();
    }

    //Auto-generated from RESTful web service wizard
    private Set<Class<?>> getRestClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();

        resources.add(com.ericsson.rest.TestResource.class);
        return resources;    
    }
}
```

Deployment Descriptor :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JAX_RS</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>rest.application.config.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The URL to get the resource :-

```
http://localhost:7001/JAX_RS/test/TestResource
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What errors do you get when deploying from Eclipse that you don't have a problem with during a manual deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider reviewing all the steps in this article:

http://me-ol-blog.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/step-by-step-tutorial-on-how-to-create.html

It shows deploying to a weblogic in Eclipse.